Подключение сканера/весов ZEBRA MP7002 к ПК через COM-порт
На кассе самообслуживания используем сканер/весы ZEBRA MP7002.
При взвешивании касса стала выдавать сообщение об ошибке (Неверный вес).
Для диагностики принято решение подключить весы/сканер к ПК используя COM-порт.
Для просмотра данных COM-порта используется программа PuTTY, TerminalCOM и подобные клиенты
Настройки подключения:

Serial - COM1
Speed - 9600
Data bits - 8
Stop bits - 1
Parity - NONE
Flow control - NONE

Но при подключении данным способом в терминале отображаются только данные сканера при сканировании, данные весов при взвешивании не отображаются. Подскажите можно ли подключить данное устройство к ПК через COM-порт чтобы посмотреть данные при взвешивании. Какие программы и настройки использовать?

Вот документация: https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/support-dam/en/documentation/unrestricted/guide/product/mp7x00-ig-en.pdf Найдите строчку: RS-232 Device Port Configuration Parameter # 1246. Там есть что-то про Scale. Там же написано, как менять параметры.
